# How to redirect to error page when requesting URL that ends with '.php'?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I created a `.htaccess` file to enable user to request a page without php extension and force redirect to a custom error page when requesting URL that ends with '.php'. Like this:

`mysite.com/home` -> `home.php` will be served

`mysite.com/home.php` -> a custom 403 forbidden will be served

My problem is when I request `mysite.com/home.php`, the `home.php` is served instead, without any error.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Exit the rule chain when showing error pages
RewriteRule ^error/403.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^error/404.php$ - [L]

# Append '.php' to every request 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

# Show 404 error page when original request ends with '.php'
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule \.php/.*$ - [L,R=404]

# Custom error 
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
```

Comment: `RewriteRule \.php/.*$` should probably be just `RewriteRule \.php$`, but I guess you will end up having everything 404ed after that, but try and see. (if you are using Apache 2.4, try putting `END` insead of `L`)

Comment: thanks. Changing it to `RewriteRule \.php$` works well, with some modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `\.php/.*$` to `\.php.*$` or `\.php$` and it's now working,.

In this case I chose the first because API support like `mysite.com/api/data1/data2/` (by accessing `api.php`).

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .htaccess file

```
<Files ~ "\.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```